# Angular 6 display specific library projects

Tags: angular, angular6

**I'd like to know if it's possible to "run"/"serve" specific library projects without using main app (app.component).**

This is the architectures of my workspace :

```
Myproject
   src
     app
        |app.component.html
        |...
   projects
     lib-1
        src
          lib
             list-component
               |list.component.html 
               |...
     lib-2
```

And I wanted test (display) only my **list-component** without use app.component.html.
Is it possible?
I tried to search about how ng-serve specific component but I didn't get working answer...

Comment: You can only serve an angular application, not a library. I always develop libraries against a dummy application before publishing them

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. So, yes I have to use dummy application in order to tests them.